# Subquery with an Exist

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join, exists, adventureworks

I am a user working in inventory management attempting to return information regarding product name, location, and its availability at the location from the adventure works 2017 database. While trying to run the query, I am getting an error message that states I have too many expressions in my subquery list and that I can only do that if I start the subquery with 'Exists'. I suppose I do not understand what I am doing wrong, maybe someone could explain how 'Exists' works? Is there a way I can rewrite this so I can return both expressions in the subquery? I will include the syntax and error message below.

```
SELECT Production.Product.Name
       ,(SELECT Production.Location.Name
         ,Production.Location.Availability
         FROM Production.Location
         WHERE Production.Location.LocationID = Production.ProductInventory.LocationID)
FROM Production.Product
    INNER JOIN Production.ProductInventory
    ON Production.Product.ProductID = Production.ProductInventory.ProductID;
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN the subquery instead.

Comment: A subquery in the SELECT clause isn't allowed to return multiple columns.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If asking reflect research. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a *subquery* here this appears to be just an outer join:

```
select p.Name, l.Name Location, l.Availability
from Production.Product p
join Production.ProductInventory i
left join Production.Location l on l.LocationID = i.LocationID
on p.ProductID = i.ProductID;
```

Note how tidier the query is by using table aliases.